# cannot write to xml properly

Tags: php, xml

I have the following problem. I am trying to create a new item in an xml file but I think something wrong with my code here is an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<urls>
  <url>
  <link>http://google.com</link>
  </url>
  </urls>
```

I just want to add another url using PHP here is how I am trying to do it

```
// Open and parse the XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("urls.xml");
     // Create a child in the first topic node
     $child = $xml->url[0]->addChild("url");
     // Add the text attribute
     $child->addAttribute("link", $url);

    // Display the new XML code
     echo $xml->asXML();
     // Store new XML code in questions.xml
     $xml->asXML("urls.xml");
```

But instead of another URL I am getting only link tag. Sorry I am new to XML. What could be wrong?

Comment: Try to do `$child->addChild("link", $url);`

Comment: What is the expected and current  output?

Answer (score 0):

try this, parse with DOM

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();//DOMDocument()
if(file_exists("urls.xml"))
$doc->load("article.xml");
$racine=$doc->documentElement;
$racine1=$doc->createElement("URL");//create element URL
$link=$doc->createElement("link"); //reate element link
$racine1->appendChild($link);   //add element link to element URL
$textlink=$doc->createTextNode("text");// create textnode with value "text"
$link->appendChild($textlink); // add textnode to element link
$racine->appendChild($racine1); // add element URl to Racine URLS
$doc->appendChild($racine);
$xml=$doc->saveXML();
$doc->save("urls.xml");
header("content-type: text/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you're telling it to do the wrong thing.

If you have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<urls>
    <url>
        <link>http://google.com</link>
    </url>
</urls>
```

And you want this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<urls>
    <url>
        <link>http://google.com</link>
    </url>
    <url>
        <link>http://stackoverflow.com</link>
    </url>
</urls>
```

But you're telling it to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<urls>
    <url>
        <link>http://google.com</link>
        <url link="http://www.stackoverflow.com" />
    </url>
</urls>
```

Try the following code instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("urls.xml");
// Create a child in the first topic node
$child = $xml->urls[0]->addChild("url");
$child->addChild("link", $url);
// Display the new XML code
echo $xml->asXML();
// Store new XML code in questions.xml
$xml->asXML("urls.xml");
```